# Avoiding HTML-in-string / html() in a jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to make a jQuery based custom popup window for my site using javascript.

I prototyped it by storing the HTML to go in the popup inside a javascript string variable and then display that string thus:

```
$('#pop_div').html(string);
```

where `string` is defined thus:

```
var string= '<div class="className">' +
    'HTML Content'+
'</div>'
```

I've seen a few websites that do this but think it is incorrect.

It works for static html snippets but not for rails generated html using <%= .. %>

What is the best way of loading HTML code generated by rails into a javascript/jquery script?

thanks

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071386/jquery-html-and-new-line-characters this does work. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fine to do

```
<script>var string = <%= escape_javascript(...) =>;</script>
```

since the `escape_javascript` does the work of ensuring that the original string will be interpreted properly by the JavaScript interpreter.

See [Why escape_javascript before rendering a partial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620113/why-escape-javascript-before-rendering-a-partial) for more discussion.

Note, that if you want to put this in an `onclick` handler instead of inside a `<script>` element you may need to `escape_javascript` and then HTML escape the result.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to store the element in a variable:

```
var el = $("<div class='className' />").html("HTML Content");

//append the element to the div
$("#pop_div").append(el);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about in 3 steps:

```
var htmlContent = 'HTML Content';

var elem = $('<div />').addClass("className").html(htmlContent);

$('#pop_div').empty().append(elem);
```

Now, I've only done "hello world" with RoR, but use Mike Samuel's `escape_javascript` code and that might address your needs.